# I am unable to access the build server agent pool

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Trying to replicate these steps

- Download and configure the agent
- Log on to the machine using the account for which you've prepared permissions as explained above.
- In your web browser, sign on to VSTS or TFS, and navigate to the Agent pools tab:
- VSTS: https://{your_account}.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool
     TFS 2017: https://{your_server}/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool
     TFS 2015: http://{your_server}:8080/tfs/_admin/_AgentPool

  **The TFS URLs doesn't work for me. How can I get the correct URL?**

**404 ERROR**

More information about this error
Page not found.

Here are some additional tips
Verify the URL you are trying to access is correct
Additional technical details:
Activity ID: 9096263d-09fb-4b59-b426-1a84e9a4b254 Date and Time: 21/09/2017 10:49:27 (UTC)

Comment: Do you use VSTS of TFS on-premise server? What is your account/TFS Collection URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For TFS 2017, the URL format should be:

  ```
  https[/http]://{your_server}[:port]/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool
  ```

  For the protocol, it’s depend on what you used for your TFS 2017 server. Such as the protocol is `http` and the port is `8080` for your TFS 2017 server, you should go to the URL http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool.
- For TFS 2015, the URL format should be:

  ```
  https[/http]://{your_server}[:port]/tfs/_admin/_AgentPool
  ```

  The protocol http or https and the port also depend on what you used for your TFS 2015 server. such as if your TFS 2015 server protocol is `http`, and the port you used is `800`, then you should go to the URL http://server:800/tfs/_admin/_AgentPool.

After accessing to the correct URL, you can continue to deploy your agent.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the URL that worked for me for TFS2017 was:

```
http://{ServerName}:8080/tfs/{CollectionName}/
```

and not the one specified in official documentation:

```
http://{ServerName}:8080/tfs/{CollectionName}/_admin/_AgentPool
```